# JWT Authentication wrong parameters

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm learning how to add JWT token authentication to my webApi. This what I have done so far inside `Startup.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
..
..
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   }

   app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
   {
     AutomaticAuthenticate = true,

     TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
     {
        ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:Port",
        ValidateAudience = false,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("testPass"))
     }
   });

   app.UseMvc();
}
```

But I'm getting errors like:

1. `JwtBearerAppBuilderExtensions.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(IApplicationBuilder, JwtBearerOptions)' is obsolete: 'See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=845470`

and

```
2. JwtBearerOptions' does not contain a definition for 'AutomaticAuthenticate'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the `ConfigureServices` method in `StartUp.cs`.

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:Port",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("YourKey")) 
            };
        });

    // other configuration...
}
```

Then in `Configure` method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it in ConfigureService rather than Configure, try something like

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
```

It will work!